# Is it possible (or advisable) to use Activity as switched component of ActionBar's navigation tab or drop-down navigation

Tags: android

I have 2 Activities. One of it is displaying line chart, another is displaying pie chart. I would like to embed both in a single launched Activity. User is allowed to perform single click, to switch between line chart and pie chart.

I realize ActionBar's navigation tab, or drop-down navigation is the best candidate to help me achieve this purpose.

From Android API demo, and guideline found from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html, I realize all switched components are implemented as `Fragment`, not `Activity`

1. Does it mean that I need to port my previous 2 Activities into 2 Fragments, in order to embed them into ActionBar's tab navigation view/ drop-down navigation view?
2. Is there any other ways I can do without porting? But, is it advisable as I do not find an official example by using Activity.
3. In API demo, I realize most Fragment is implemented in the following pattern.

---

```
public class FragmentStack extends Activity {
    ...
    public static class CountingFragment extends Fragment {
        // CountingFragment never access any members in FragmentStack
    }
}
```

Is there any reason to do so? Why don't they have `CountingFragment` is a separated file?

Comment: Just suggestion, you cant switch between those charts in single activity, with swipe, using ViewPager. Might be cool :)

Comment: I avoid using ViewPager, as the chart itself is handling its own horizontal swipe and vertical swipe event. It will confusing user if I place them in ViewPager.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to embed in a single activity, the preferred way is to use fragments. You could probably also use custom views, but Fragments have a well defined lifecycle and handle a lot thigs for you. So it might be a good idea to extract functionality into fragments, and have the activities only as shells, embedding the fragments (if you still need this with your new design). You can switch between fragments any way you like: with buttons, dropdowns or any other UI that fits your app; you don't necessarily have to use the action bar. As for 3. there is nothing wrong with defining fragments in separate files. Activity and fragment are in the same file in samples mostly to make it easier to follow the sample.